# Change a SKSpriteNode Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i'm new to sprite Kit and having an issue with changing a current SKSpriteNode image.

My spriteNode looks like this

```
mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:Texture1];
[mover setScale:1.0];
[self addChild:mover];
```

then i have this method that should change the mover image, but it is not. What am i doing wrong?

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == worldCategory) {
        SKTexture* explodeTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"explode"];
        explodeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

        mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:explodeTexture1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to change the texture property of your mover object.

Something like this:

```
mover.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"explode"];
```

Answer (score 8):

This method is actually re-creating the the mover object.

```
mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:explodeTexture1];
```

You just need to update the texture with:

```
mover.texture = explodeTexture1;
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift version:

```
mover.texture = SKTexture.textureWithImageNamed("explode")
```

Swift version 3.0:

```
mover.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "explode")
```